# Libraries to read a csv file in java

Tags: java

I would like to know if there are any inbuilt libraries to read csv files into a java program, just like the DOM and SAX parser libraries that are available to read XML files. Can you please list out them, if any?

PS: I would prefer not to write the logic of parsing them using tokenizer in java as I am reluctant to meddle with the other complexities involved in doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not specific to java-me, in Java EE and Java SE environments I use [javacvs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/)

Answer (score 2):

Please Try this

[Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)